# Get type error cannot destructure property as it is undefined in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a MongoDB collection and inside this collection, there are some documents. In these documents, I stored some IDs of another collection documents. This is an image of this document.

[image: An image of a document]

In the frontend, I access this document and get the `postId`. I tried this way.

```
const onePostId=posts.postId
console.log(onePostId);
const type=typeof (onePostId);
console.log(type);
```

This code part gives me this result.

[image: Image of the result]

I try to pass this `postId` to an API `` const response = await axios.get(`/buyerGetOnePost/${onePostId}`) `` like this way. But this `postId` is a string type I think that's why I can't get results from this API. Then I try like this `const {onePostId}=posts.postId` then I get an error that says "TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'onePostId' of 'posts.postId' as it is undefined". How do I solve this problem?

This is the complete code that I tried.

```
function PostsLocation() {

    const { offerId } = useParams();
    console.log(offerId);

    const [posts, setPosts] = useState({});

    useEffect(()=>{
        getOnePost();
    }, []);

    const getOnePost = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`/buyerGetOneSellerOffer/${offerId}`)
            console.log(response);
            const allPost=response.data.oneOffer;
            setPosts(allPost);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Error: ${error}`)
        }
    }
    console.log(posts);

    const onePostId=posts.postId
    console.log(onePostId);
    const type=typeof (onePostId);
    console.log(type);

    const [offerPosts, setOfferPosts] = useState({});

    useEffect(()=>{
        getOneOfferPost();
    }, []);

    useEffect(()=>{
        if (offerPosts && offerPosts.location) {
            console.log(offerPosts.location);
            console.log(offerPosts.location.longitude);
            console.log(offerPosts.location.latitude);
        }
    }, [offerPosts]);

    const getOneOfferPost = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`/buyerGetOnePost/${onePostId}`)
            console.log(response);
            const allOfferPost=response.data.onePost;
            setOfferPosts(allOfferPost);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Error: ${error}`)
        }
    }
    console.log(offerPosts);

    const long = offerPosts?.location?.longitude;
    console.log(long);
    const lat=offerPosts?.location?.latitude;
    console.log(lat);

    const location={lat,long};

}
```

Below image shows the results after `console.log(posts)`.
[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific? As per my understanding, you got the API's response correctly and are storing it in `posts` . Where are you facing the issue after that?

Comment: @NeERAJTK I try to get the `postId` from the above-mentiontioned document and I get it as I mentioned in the above second image. Then I try to pass that `postId` to this API `/buyerGetOnePost/${onePostId}`. This is where I get an issue. I think because the `postId` is a string. But I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: Can you share the full code?

Comment: @NeERAJTK I edited this and added the full code that I tried.

Comment: @NeERAJTK I added another image that shows the results after `console.log(posts)`.

Comment: when you destructuring the property `onePostId` which doesn't exist on posts. that's why you get the error.  So, destructure the postId like this `const {onePostId:postId} = posts` or the regular way `const onePostId = posts.postId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to destructure a value without getting the data first. So, you are getting a error.

You are running the below code for posts at starting when it doesn't have any data

```
 const onePostId=posts.postId
```

and only after the call to

```
    getOnePost();
```

your data gets filled but there is a time delay which you should always consider with async await syntax and you should first check if posts contain posts.postId with some value or if defined and then do the destructuring. If it doesn't then probably don't use it either wait for it or return loading or return mock value probably.

eg:

```
if(!posts.postId){
        //  posts.postId is not set and it doesn't have data 
}
```

Comment: I understand what the issue is. But I do not understand how to solve it. How do I wait to come for posts data? What should I do?

Comment: You are already waiting for the data to be set ( you have used async await) but before the data is set on posts you should probably render the code conditionally , you could probably return a simple div with a loading statement like so or initialize with mock value and so on..